# Comparing two vectors in a different order and obtaining position of matches

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a matrix where the colnames are sample names and I have created a vector of the colnames.

I also have a vector of sample names I need to subset from the matrix which I have found are not in the same order as the colnames of the matrix.

To subset the matrix I need to find which columns in the matrix correspond to the samples I need.

To illustrate this:

```
colnames <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I")

sample_names<- c("B","D","I")
```

I need a way to get R to return the position information such that for the example sample names "B","D","I", the colnames position is: [1] 2 4 9

Comment: `which(colnames==sample_names)` ?? (if it's to subset the matrix m: `m[,colnames(m)==sample_names]` should be enough too (subseting by logical vector)

Comment: you need the "position of matches" but yet you didn't try `match`, how come ? `match(c("B","D","I"), c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"))` gives `[1] 2 4 9`...

Comment: Because I'm new to R and I didn't realise the command existed. This is how I ended up doing it in the end. Thanks for the reply

Comment: glad that it helped. 2 things that can help you when in need for a specific function: `help.search("keyword")` (so here, `help.search("match")`, which, among other, proposes `match`) and "googling"...

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
> m=matrix(rep(1:4,3),ncol=4)
> colnames(m)<-c("A","C","D","B")
> m
     A C D B
[1,] 1 4 3 2
[2,] 2 1 4 3
[3,] 3 2 1 4

> vec<-c("A","B")
> vec
[1] "A" "B"
```

To answer your exact question, use `which`, it will return the index of TRUE values in a logical vector.

```
> which(colnames(m)==vec)
[1] 1 4
```

But as your goal seems to be subsetting the matrix, just use directly the sample names vector to get it like this:

```
> m[, vec]
     A B
[1,] 1 2
[2,] 2 3
[3,] 3 4
```

Comment: actually just `m[, vec]` should do

Comment: For some reason
    
    m[, vec]

didn't subset the colnames that I wanted, rather it subsetted the first 70 colnames in a random order which is equal to the number of samples in my list.

The match function ended up answering my question then I used the positions to subset.

Comment: @YuriyGrabovsky without knowing your data there's no way to explain why it didn't work on it. I've no divination skill, so try reading the [help] and [ask] to write better question :)